# How to stop gravity option screwing up imagemagick parenthesised inputs?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've been battling with this error (bug?) in imagemagick:

```
% convert \
> \( logo: -crop 100x100+300+300 -gravity west \) \
> \( logo: -crop 100x100+300+300 -gravity west \) \
> +append out.png
convert: geometry does not contain image ("100x100+300+490") `LOGO' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/599.
```

Where does the number 490 come from??

ImageMagick's example image `logo:` is 640x480px. The crop geometry `100x100+300+300` is clearly entirely within the 640x480 bounds of `logo:`.

Of course the output I am expecting is the side-by-side of two identical `100x100+300+300` crops from `logo:`

[image]

But I am getting this funky error instead. If a previous parenthesised input image has a `-gravity` switch, then subsequent parenthesised inputs have their crop geometries warped in different ways:

```
% convert \( logo: -gravity east \) \( logo: -crop 10x10+630+470 \) +append  out.png
convert: geometry does not contain image ("10x10+0+705") `LOGO' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/599.
```

How can I prevent any `-gravity` switches in parenthesised input images from affecting other parenthesised inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three suggestions...

First, the "-gravity" setting should be before the operation that uses it.

After the operation that the uses the "-gravity" setting put just "+gravity" to end the setting.

If you use "-respect-parenthesis" before the parentheses, then the "-gravity" settings you make inside the parentheses won't continue to be in effect after them. You can use "+respect-parenthesis" to end that setting.

Comment: It looks like `-respect-parenthesis` just fixes every problem I currently have and every problem I ever will have, dream-come-true. I wonder why it's not the default.